# Can't call setState

Tags: reactjs, fetch, state, require, fs

I have had to change my code from using `fetch` to `require` within my react app for use within electron. Since doing so I have got the following error:

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.
>   This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.
>   Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
>   class property with the desired state in the App component.

I understand *why* I'm getting this error but I am lost as to how to fix this based on my current code. I'm mainly confused as to why this happens when moving from `fetch` to `require` too.

Current Code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      config:{
        nlinks:[],
        },
        numPages: null,
        pageNumber: 1,
      popup: null,
      pdf:null,
      homelhs:"",
      homerhs:"",
      currentNlink:0,
      currentClink:0,

      };

      const json = require('../public/config.json');
      for (var n=0 ; n<json.nlinks.length ; n++)
      {
        json.nlinks[n].state = (n===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
        json.nlinks[n].currentChapter = 0; // create field dynamically
        if (json.nlinks[n].chapters)
        {
          if (!json.nlinks[n].test) json.nlinks[n].test={state:0,submitted:0,title:"dummy",questions:[]}; // create dummy test dynamically
          for (var q=0 ; q<json.nlinks[n].test.questions.length ; q++)
          {
            json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].response=0;
            json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].correct=false;
          }
          for(var c=0 ; c<json.nlinks[n].chapters.length ; c++)
          {
            json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].state = (c===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
            if (json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections)
            {
              json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].currentSection=0; 
              for (var s=0 ; s<json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections.length ; s++)
              {
                json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections[s].state = (s===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
              }
            }
            else
            {
              json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections=[];
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          json.nlinks[n].chapters=[];
        }
      }
      this.setState({config: json,});

      this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
//      this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }
```

Original Code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      config:{
        nlinks:[],
        },
        numPages: null,
        pageNumber: 1,
      popup: null,
      pdf:null,
      homelhs:"",
      homerhs:"",
      currentNlink:0,
      currentClink:0,

      };


      fetch('config.json')
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((json) =>{
          //console.log(json);
          //json defines the module NavLink s and their content - so save it to App state
          for (var n=0 ; n<json.nlinks.length ; n++)
          {
            json.nlinks[n].state = (n===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
            json.nlinks[n].currentChapter = 0; // create field dynamically
            if (json.nlinks[n].chapters)
            {
              if (!json.nlinks[n].test) json.nlinks[n].test={state:0,submitted:0,title:"dummy",questions:[]}; // create dummy test dynamically
              for (var q=0 ; q<json.nlinks[n].test.questions.length ; q++)
              {
                json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].response=0;
                json.nlinks[n].test.questions[q].correct=false;
              }
              for (var c=0 ; c<json.nlinks[n].chapters.length ; c++)
              {
                json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].state = (c===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
                if (json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections)
                {
                  json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].currentSection=0; 
                  for (var s=0 ; s<json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections.length ; s++)
                  {
                    json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections[s].state = (s===0?1:0); // create state field dynamically
                  }
                }
                else
                {
                  json.nlinks[n].chapters[c].sections=[];
                }
              }
            }
            else
            {
              json.nlinks[n].chapters=[];
            }
          }
          this.setState({config: json,});

          });

      this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
//      this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);

}
```

[link to full app.js](https://gist.github.com/BHWD/3cf9a326e8562e3bc76d702448a91995)

Within `Render() { }` I am trying the following:

```
if (this.state.homerhs==='')
          {
            fs.readFile('resources/app.asar/build/pages/home.rhs.html', 'utf8', function(err, homerhsrequire) {
              console.log(err);
              console.log(homerhsrequire);
              homerhsrequire=homerhsrequire.replace(/src="/g,'src="./pages/');
              homerhsrequire=homerhsrequire.replace(/src='/g,"src='./pages/");
              //this.setState({homerhs:homerhsrequire});
              this.state.homerhs = homerhsrequire;
            });       

          }
```

However this returns:

> App.js:708 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of
>   undefined

Comment: Can you share the full component code? We need it in order to give you an answer. In any case, when you are in the constructor, you should assign to `this.state` directly, instead of using `this.setState`

Comment: Add link to gist file

Answer (score 2):

Don't call this.setState() in constructor and move your fetch call to componentDidMount lifecylce method.
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is not available in the constructor - use `this.state` in the constructor.

Best practice is to use any type of fetching in `componentDidMount`. Ideally you'd have some redux logic and do the fetching in an action - this way you could just wire up you component with some redux state attributes that are set as a result of calling the action that make `fetch` call.

Comment: I have a function (`fetchHTML`) in the same component as my `componentDidMount` that has a fetch within. I cannot move this function to `componentDidMount` though and i'm not familiar with redux. IS there a way that I could pass the `state` data back to `componentDidMount` but keep my `fs.readFile` in it's own function `fetchHTML`?

Comment: You can access the state in componentDidMount by this.state . Does this answer the question?

Comment: I have just tried doing this however I get: `App.js:774 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample of what I am referring to above